# leveldb-library Fails to Build in Xcode 9.0

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, xcode9, leveldb

leveldb-library is installed as a dependency of Firebase/Core 4.2.0. When I go to build my project I get three errors from the pod.

[image: Terminal pod install]

[image: xcode errors]

I have looked around and leveldb is maintained by Google with the current version sitting at 1.20. The pod leveldb-library is currently at 1.18.3. I'm not sure if Google needs to update the pod leveldb-library, or if Firebase needs to change their dependencies.

Until then, I'm going to use Firebase/Code version 4.0.2 which still builds and runs fine. Let me know if there's any other information you need.

Comment: This may be a corrupt Xcode state issue. The latest leveldb-library builds fine for me on Xcode 9. Try wiping DerivedData.